# How to use read timeout with fmemopen

Tags: c, io

I can set timeout for `read` from STDIN by using

```
    struct termios  raw = ...;
    /*
     * Timeout on read.
     */
    raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &raw);
```

How can I set timeout for `fread` and a `FILE*` created by `fmemopen`?

Comment: You'd be reading from memory. *what* do you expect to time out?

Comment: @Shawn I want to timeout when I reach the end, right now it blocks